# What does <!-- //--> mean in ASP?

Tags: html, asp-classic

```
<script language="javascript">
    <!--    
             //some logic here 
    //-->
</script>
```

What does `<!-- //-->` mean? . I thought they were comment, however, the double slash before --> puzzles me.

Comment: I'm torn as to whether this should still have the [tag:asp-classic] and not [tag:javascript] tag instead...

Answer (score 8):

That has nothing to do with ASP. That's a historical artifact from when Javascript was new and not supported in all browsers. `<!--` is a legitimate component of the JS language itself, and is treated as a "do nothing" command. `-->` however, is **NOT** part of JS, so you have to escape it using a proper JS comment, hence `//-->`

All this is just to hide the JS code from stoneage/obsolete browsers which didn't understand the `<script>` tag. Remember that browsers ignore tags which they don't recognize. A non-JS browser would skip over `<script>` and start outputting the JS code as text.  Hence the comment sequence. Even if the browser doesn't understand `<script>` and `</script>` it WILL understand an HTML comment, and skip over all of the code.

E.g. if you loaded a modern JS-enabled page in Netscape 1.0 and had something like:

```html
<script>
  alert('hello, world!');
</script>
<foo>
  Hello again
</foo>
```

Then you wouldn't get an alert, you'd actually see

```
alert('hello, world!');Hello again
```

in the browser window. But if you had

```
<script>
<!--
   alert('hello, world!');
//-->
</script>
<foo>
   Hello again
</foo>
```

then you'd only see

```
 Hello again
```